# Should firing related questions be allowed on this site?

Tags: discussion

Recently a question related to firing was closed as too localized.

[Getting fired on the second day, how do I cope with it?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/911/getting-fired-on-the-second-day-is-it-fair)

- Some people can argue, this question is not localized and quite general.
- Some say this is rant
- Some say this is not constructive
- some say there is not enough detail
- some say this is not answerable

My question is:

**Should a question related to firing be allowed here in the first place. Because it is probable that**

- If you provide detail, that makes the question too localize hence off topic
- If you don't provide detail, there is not enough detail so it is not answerable
- if you already got fired, this is not constructive. You already lost your job. What are you asking for? This is just a rant.

**So in what capacity a firing related question be allowed here, if it is allowed in the first place?**

Comment: Your edit has brought the question back on topic but invalidated the answer you have already accepted.  Do you plan to address that?

Comment: @Chad, what I really wanted to ask is `Is is acceptable to fire someone on second day`. But looks like I wont be able to post that question. I am still happy with the accepted answer. I wanted to bring the question in a format that complies with the site.

Comment: The problem is that answer does not really answer the current question.

Answer (score 9):

The question [Getting fired on the second day, how do I cope with it?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/911/getting-fired-on-the-second-day-is-it-fair) is pretty lousy.
I'm not saying this to be mean, but the title alone made my brain drop into a petulant, whiny voice - "*I got fired! It's not faiiirrrrr! I was working harrrrrd!*".
Add to that the fact that the best answer anyone can offer you is "Unless you had a contract stating otherwise you're out of luck.", or the harsher version "Life's not fair." and I think it's unsalvageable.

(It's a badly-worded (ranty/whiny) question, probably Too Localized since any recourse depends on your contract, and the answers I can come up with would make us sound like evil dickwolves.)

---

Having said that, ***SOME*** "questions about firing" may be on topic - The following are some very general (*probably overly general*) categories of questions I would consider to be "on topic":

- I was instructed to fire {someone, X people, ...} - How can I break it to them gently?
- We just fired someone with access to sensitive things, what steps should we take to ensure the company's security?
- I was fired from my last job, I believe unfairly. How do I explain this at interviews without looking like I'm badmouthing my former employer?
- Is it appropriate to ask for a reference from my boss if I was laid off (fired for economic reasons)?

Comment: rephrased my question btw. I am not sure if it is still in the scope though.

Comment: @rocketscience Your edit doesn't change things - this *type* of firing question is a bad fit because there's nothing we can do for you here.  If you want to know ***why*** you have to ask the person who fired you (unanswerable, also the sad fact is most employment is at will so you can be fired (or quit) for virtually any reason, or no for reason). If you want to know what your recourses are you need to review your employment contract (Too Localized) and/or local employment laws (We Aren't Lawyers).  If you want advice on how to spin it I'd open a new question.

Comment: Lets agree on firing questions and delete it if it is out of scope.

Comment: @rocketscience - it is not the firing that is out of scope.  It is the whining rant that is out of scope.